# twitter bootstrap button action + opening a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for a form.

A button needs to validate the form and then present a modal. I realized that the button doesn't validates the form if I just point it to toggle the modal.

```
<button id="button3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentDisclaimerModal">button 3</button>
```

I decided to show modal using javascript.

```
<button id="button3" onclick="$(#paymentDisclaimerModal).modal('show');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentDisclaimerModal">button 3</button>
```

Not working! Am I supposed to user a separate javascript block? Help much appreciated.

Comment: How do you validate the form? From what I understand, you need to attach a method to your button click event that performs the validation and shows the modal if it's successful

Comment: You have a typo in your JavaScript, you need quotes around `#paymentDisclaimerModal`: `"$('#paymentDisclaimerModal').modal('show');"`

Comment: thanks! Even after that, the modal opens up when I click the button, how can I avoid opeing the modal if the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code seems to be wrong:

```
<button id="button3" onclick="$(#paymentDisclaimerModal).modal('show');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentDisclaimerModal">button 3</button>
```

The jQuery selector must be a valid string, change it to:

```
<button id="button3" onclick="$('#paymentDisclaimerModal').modal('show');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentDisclaimerModal">button 3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is working now, but still the the button opens up the modal without validating. I do not want to show modal if the textbox is empty.

Comment: How are you validating your form? I can't see no constraint on validation, just a `modal('show')` on button click